# Wordpress functions in Laravel

Tags: wordpress, laravel, laravel-4

could anyone explain, is it possible include WP functions into Laravel blade.template?

I have WP installation and want create one folder for an app on Laravel. These functions i want include:

```
<?php require( '../wp-load.php' ); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

How i can implement this feature?
Thx in advance!

Comment: Solution is http://grossi.io/2014/working-with-laravel-4-and-wordpress-together/...But one question..is it possible include extern file into folder Laravel?

Answer (score 3):

### 1. Add WordPress to `app/vendor`

<del>Download WordPress into the vendor folder (`./vendor/wordpress`)</del>

User `require` in composer.json, see (3).

### 2. Find the function location

Check the Codex page for the function you need, let's say [esc_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url), as you can see in that page, the function resides in `wp-includes/formatting.php`

### 3. Include the file containg the function

Include that file, use your `composer.json` file then run the command `composer update`

```
"require": {
    ...
    "johnpbloch/wordpress": "4.*"
},
"autoload": {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    "files": [
        ...
        "wordpress/wp-includes/formatting.php"
    ]
},
```

### 4. Use the function in Blade

```
{{-- file: app/views/example.blade.php }}

{{ esc_html( '<a href="http://www.example.com/">A link</a>' ) }}
```

This outputs:

```
&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.example.com/&quot;&gt;A link&lt;/a&gt;
```

Comment: How can this example help me?